# why do i keep getting 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client' error?

Tags: node.js, authentication, encryption, jwt, cryptojs

Okay i am fairly new to node js and i am learning user authentication. I keep getting the 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client' error. can someone just tell me what is wrong with my code and how to fix it?. When i test it in postman, The register route works, its the login route that gives me this problem. Here is my code:

```
const User = require('../models/User')
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const {BadRequestError, UnauthenticatedError} = require('../errors')
const Register = async (req, res)=>{

    const newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(req.body.password, process.env.pass_secret ).toString(),
    });

    if(newUser){
        const savedUser = await newUser.save();
        res.status(201).json(savedUser);
    }
}


const Login = async (req, res) =>{

    const {username} = req.body

    //checking if both the email and password are provided
    if(!username){
        throw new BadRequestError('please provide a username and password')
    }
    
    //finding a user with the email, if the user doesnt exist, return an error
    const user = await User.findOne({username: req.body.username});
    if(!user){
        throw new UnauthenticatedError('Invalid username or password')
    }

    //checking if the passwords match
    const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt( user.password, process.env.pass_secret);

    const originalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    
        
    if(originalPassword !== req.body.password){
        throw new UnauthenticatedError('Invalid email or password')
    } 
    const accessToken = jwt.sign( { id: user._id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin}, process.env.jwt_secret, {expiresIn:"30d"});
  
    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;  
    res.status(200).json({...others, accessToken});
}

module.exports = {Register, Login}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you have this:

```
if(newUser){
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedUser);
}
```

You need to change it to:

```
if(newUser){
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedUser);
    return;
}
```

You don't want the code to continue after you've done

```
res.status(201).json(savedUser);
```

because it will then try to send another response.

In addition, everywhere you have this:

```
if (err) throw err;
```

inside an async callback, you need to replace that with something that actually sends an error response such as:

```
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
    return;
}
```

Comment: im sorry i forgot to mention that the register route is working fine. It is when i try to log in after i have created a user using the register route that i get that error. i dont know if that affects your answer.

Comment: I think adding return statement at the end of Login function will solve the error